Does the whole chimney stack need to be removed?
Our next-door neighbour was having roof repairs when it was discovered that the chimney stack was actually resting on timber struts and is very dangerous - this only occurs under their side of the chimney - is it best to have the whole chimney stack removed or just half?


Brick chimneys are very heavy.  If not well supported they can fall down and make a big mess, plus hurting(or worst) anyone close by.  This is a good job to have a structural engineer check.  You want to know it is well supported, not just think it is.
